# Importing an OpenCV project into Eclipse

Tags: android, opencv, import, android-ndk

I have imported OpenCV and am able to run all the sample codes. I have to now work on an already built app. How do I import this project? This app uses OpenCV.

EDIT: I am a beginner to opencv for android.  The OpenCV tutorials tell me how to create a new project, not how to import it.

Comment: I suggest you search for how to import *ANY* project into Eclipse. There should be no differences unless the project you want to import has the OpenCV jars / library files embedded in it. Your question is too broad to answer accurately - just try it, see what happens then come back with another question if you have problems.

Comment: It does not work. There are OpenCV library files.

Answer (score 0):

If the project is already from another eclipse and the versions are compatible, you can move the project folder into the workspace folder on the file system, copy/paste into the project explorer (Java Perspective) or use the 'Import > File System' function.

If the project is a bunch of raw project files, you can use the 'File > Import..' function in eclipse, choose '..Existing Project..'

Then you should be all set.

If you're starting anew with just .java files and android xml etc. You'll then need to include the the OpenCV project in the workspace and add the project to your app's project, as listed here from OpenCV's documentation of "Using the Android Binary Packages":

*"Do the right mouse click on your app in Package Explorer, go to Properties ‣ Android ‣ Library ‣ Add "*

Here's the link for that:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

Answer (score 0):

import it to the workspace.AS usually you import any other project.If there is any error share the error.I think this is the correct way.